# Why does numpy.vectorize give a warning about an invalid value when using uncertainties?

Tags: python, numpy

With Python 3.10, numpy 1.23.5, and [uncertainties](https://uncertainties-python-package.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) 3.1.7 (on Linux; specifically using packages from conda-forge on Fedora 37), the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
from uncertainties.core import Variable


x = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
y = np.array([np.nan, np.nan], dtype=float)
func = np.vectorize(lambda x, y: Variable(x, y), otypes=[object])
func(x, y)
```

produces:

```
/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py:2411: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in <lambda> (vectorized)
  outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
```

Using `warnings.simplefilter("error")`, I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    z = func(x, y)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2328, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2411, in _vectorize_call
    outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in <lambda> (vectorized)
```

If I change the input to use all finite floats like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from uncertainties.core import Variable


x = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
y = np.array([1.0, 1.0], dtype=float)
func = np.vectorize(lambda x, y: Variable(x, y), otypes=[object])
func(x, y)
```

or change the code to use a custom class instead of `Variable` like this:

```py
import numpy as np


class Variable:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


x = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
y = np.array([np.nan, np.nan], dtype=float)
func = np.vectorize(lambda x, y: Variable(x, y), otypes=[object])
func(x, y)
```

then no warning is issued.

What is causing this warning from numpy? It comes from compiled code that pdb can not step into. I don't see anything in the uncertainties code for `Variable` that should error or otherwise be different from a standard Python class like my third example.

I note that this code:

```
import numpy as np
from uncertainties.core import Variable


x = np.array([1.0, 2.0])
y = np.array([np.nan, np.nan], dtype=float)
[Variable(ix, iy) for ix, iy in zip(x, y)]
```

produces no error, so there is not actually a problem with passing these arguments to `Variable`. It seems to be that numpy is examining something about the types or dimensions of the arguments to the vectorized function and detects something that does not match what it expects.

Here I tried to provide a simple invocation of `numpy.vectorize`. The actual case where I encountered this was with [uncertainties.unumpy.uarray](https://github.com/lebigot/uncertainties/blob/804adccf3401aeacbcbae0d669f92131fcd02c03/uncertainties/unumpy/core.py#L291-L296) which uses `numpy.vectorize` similarly to my example.

Comment: First, remember `vectorize` is not a speed tool; it just a convenience with calling a scalar-input function with broadcastable arrays.  For now skip it.  Try `Variable(1.0, np.nan)` etc., and use a list comprehension to work with multiple pairs.  Since it's a Warning I won't ask a error traceback.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to `vectorize` a function that displays its inputs, `def foo(x,y): print(x,y)\n return bar(x,y)`.  The idea is to give you a clear idea of what values `vectorize` is passing to `bar`.   Then you can better distinguish between `vectorize` issues and `bar` issues.

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj! The actual case where I encountered the warning was in a third party function `uarray` that called `vectorize`. I edited my question to point to that function. Still, `uarray` is very simple and I can replace my use of it with a comprehension that bypasses `vectorize`. Just curious, if `vectorize` is not a speed tool, why does it call into C code, making debugging this warning more difficult?

Comment: I also edited the question to provide a traceback which I obtained by using the `warnings` module to turn the warning into an exception.

Comment: I don't know what's going on.  Without downloading this undercertainties package I can't explore it myself.  Since you are using `object` otypes, you could use `np.frompyfunc` directly.  That's like `vectorize` but always returns object dype, and doesn't other bells-n-whistles.  It used to be faster, though `vectorize` has improved somewhat in recent versions.  My point about not being a speed tool, is it does not compile your function.  It has to call that once for each argument pair.

Comment: Regarding why `vectorize` calls into C code, this is speculation, but I think the answer might just be that it uses `frompyfunc` to handle broadcasting of inputs and that is implemented in C because it is more natural to define a ufunc in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the [source of uncertanities](https://github.com/lebigot/uncertainties/blob/804adccf3401aeacbcbae0d669f92131fcd02c03/uncertainties/core.py#L2798). You will find that it checks if the supplied uncertanity is negative, by the statement `std_dev < 0`.

Your supplied uncertanity (`std_dev` in the code) is NaN.This is normally fine. Running `np.nan < 0` should always be `False` according to IEEE745, and is not supposed to be an error.

But when doing that comparison inside a `np.fromfunc` raises a warning. And `np.vectorize` calls `fromfunc` under the hood. Why it fails? I have no idea. Simplest reproduction I could make:

```
import numpy as np
np.seterr(all='raise')
func = np.frompyfunc(lambda x: x<0,nin=1,nout=1)
func(1)            # is ok
func(np.nan)       # is not ok
```

I suggest you skip vectorization, and go via a list comprehension. It will give reasonable speed, I suppose, and you work around this bug.

Comment: Thanks @LudvigH! With your answer, I was able to find [this discussion](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/21416) in the numpy issue tracker which provides some more context. From that discussion, I take that the CPU sets an error flag on some floating point operations which Python ignores in the case of comparison to NaN. The numpy C code though does not ignore this flag and prints a warning when it occurs. The `frompyfunc` wrapping causes numpy to notice this flag set when the Python code is executed. Workarounds are to stay in pure Python like suggested before or suppress numpy warnings.

Comment: Nice find! Thanks for the link!

Comment: `np.array([-1,2,np.nan])<0` does not raise this warning, but  `np.array([-1,2,np.nan], dtype=object)<0`does,  I've observed that math on object dtype arrays is essentially a list comprehension, apply the 'operator' individually to each element.  Maybe this is evidence that it is using `frompyfunc` under the covers.