# Why does NaN-comparisons warn only inside np.frompyfunc?

Tags: python, numpy, nan, numpy-ufunc

If you compare `np.nan` to some other value *and you do it in a `np.frompyfunc`*, will raise a warning. Why is this? Is it a bug or a feature?

```py
import numpy as np
func = np.frompyfunc(lambda x: x<0,nin=1,nout=1)
print(func(1))            # False, no warning
print(np.nan<0)           # False
print(func(np.nan))       # False, and raises a warning
```

###### Background and Motivation

I ran into this while debugging [Why does numpy.vectorize give a warning about an invalid value when using uncertainties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75656026/why-does-numpy-vectorize-give-a-warning-about-an-invalid-value-when-using-uncert) The root cause was hidden behind both `np.vectorize` and some other library code. So understanding that float comparison changes semantics in a `frompyfunc` was a bit hard. It comes across as a bug to me.

In my own code, I like to use `np.seterr(all='raise')` and `with np.errstate(some_group='ignore'): ...` to make sure all warnings about float errors are handeled correctly and warnings are ignored only where I know it is safe. Therefore, I would like to know why this compare-with-nan is only occasionally warning.

Comment: What warning do you get? I see no warnings with the above code.

Comment: @chepner, with 'raise', the error is `FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in <lambda> (vectorized)` when `np.nan` is one of the values.  (or a `RuntimeWarning`).  That's true even if the `lambda` itself produces a valid `bool`.

Comment: I'm closing this since it is answered in your other question.

Comment: @hpaulj Even with `np.seterr(all='raise')`, I don't see any warning from either of the calls to `func` shown.

Comment: @chepner, could it be a version issue?  I see it with `1.23`.  The duplicate talks about an issue with `np.frompyfunc` passing a `c` warning through.

Comment: @hpaulj Possibly; I'm testing with 1.24.2. (Not worth me pressing the point if others can, in fact, reproduce the issue.)

Comment: For future reference: the answer to this question is a comment to my answer in the other question